# JBPM 5.3 service task

Tags: jbpm

I have created my own service task  in jbpm eclipse tooling 5.3. I want to export so that other people can use it. Can anyone help me regarding this.

In jBPM we have two service tasks log and email, I have developed my own service task in my system and I want to export so that others can use it in their system. If the solution is creating own service repository, how to create our own service repository.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation in jbpm.org
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

jBPM provides a public service repository which contains contributed reusable services. You can provide your own service task implementation as Pull Request to this: https://github.com/kiegroup/jbpm-work-items